# How to create a fading banner like with SO's badges?

Tags: .net, javascript, mootools

Using .NET, mootools/JavaScript.

I want to create a trophy mechanism similar to SO's badges.
So when a user recieves a trophy, a small fading DIV will appear at the top of his page.
Problem is, I need to keep checking against my DB if the user recieved a new trophy or not.

How would you approach it?
Would love to get code samples if you did something similar.

Comment: Why is needing to keep checking against your DB if the user recieved a new trophy or not a problem? Also, the question is a bit vague. The UI bit is just `$('newTrophyNotify').fadeIn('slow')`. :)

Comment: Agree that I'm a bit vague at the point. I'm still thinking how to approach it, should I re-get the AJAX response every X seconds? Should I just load it once when page loads? How does SO do it? I'm just in a mess here... would love to just find a tool that does that for me... (my speech ended up whining..)

Comment: Does this thing even have an official name I can look for? (Like "Lightbox" or "accordion")

Comment: You won't probably find a tool which handles the polling *and* the UI feedback. But since the UI feedback is trivial (see above), the polling is the only thing that's tricky. There are considerations besides the DB efficiency - do you really want to interrupt users in the middle of what they're doing to show a big fat notification about "you've received a rotten tomato"? I think SO does this on each page load, to minimize the interruption. But if you already have a discreet notification system (like Facebook), then you might just want to AJAX-poll a precomputed setting every X seconds.

Comment: Essentially, what I'm blabbering about is exactly what @Tracker1 suggests in their answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271639/how-to-create-a-fading-banner-like-with-sos-badges/2271659#2271659

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you already using mootools for the client-side interaction?  Look at the FX stuff in mootools.  Essentially you'll want to have a script check for server-side updates in a queue for a user every X seconds.  From the response, you can inject an object into the DOM with absolute positioning.  Having the appropriate stuff.  Within FX you have tweening where you can have it animate the showing/hiding of the item in question.  The server-side piece (ASP.Net) would probably be best handled as an ASMX, ASHX, or WCF service endpoint.  You can use the JsonSerializer to encode your responses for the service.

If you need more specific information, I would suggest posting a more specific question.